# Declaring Arrays In x86 Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm, att

I am learning Assembly and I need to make a large array. I have looked around at how to declare arrays and I have come across this.

```
array db 10 dup(?)
```

Where an array of 10 uninitialized bytes is declared. I tried this and tried to assemble it and get "error: comma expected after operand 1". I realized that the '?' is not supported in x86 so I made it a constant and got the same error. I ended up doing this.

```
array db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

This worked! But the problem is, I need large arrays (~100-400 integers) and their values will not always be known. I could write out 400 0's but I figured there must be an easier way. So is there a better way to declare large arrays?

I am using x86_64 Assembly on an Intel-Based Macbook Pro with AT&T syntax.

Comment: Based upon the `array TIMES...` answer working for you, I assume you are using `nasm` (Intel syntax) not AT&T syntax?

Comment: If you are using NASM assembler then "array db 10 dup(?)" should work as it is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Kaustav.  No it isn't, maybe you're thinking of MASM.  [This errors on NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545696/declaring-arrays-in-x86-assembly#comment98017937_29561021).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try `TIMES directive`.Use this code for declaring an array of a given size.

```
array TIMES 8 DB 0
```

This will create an array of size 8

Refer to this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm) for more.

Comment: Yes the `dup` is MASM.

Comment: This is NASM syntax; the question was asking about AT&T / GAS syntax.

Answer (score 11):

The AT&T syntax is used by [the GNU assembler](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html). The directive you're looking for is [`.fill <count>\[, <data-size>\[, <value>\]\]`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC91). In the specific case of 400 bytes:

```
array:  .fill  400
```

`data-size` defaults to `1` (byte). I believe the `value` that fills the 400 bytes defaults to zero.

---

If you are actually using the `nasm` assembler (which is Intel format, not AT&T), then the `times` directive will work, as avinash indicated, as long as you want to *predefine* the data in either the `.text` or `.data` section. However, if you need to reserve bytes in the `.bss` section (in `nasm`), you can use the `resb` (reserve byte) directive:

```
       setion .bss
       ...
arr1   resb  400             ; Reserve 400 bytes (uninitialized)
arr2   times 400 resb 1      ;  Same thing, using times
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on which assembler you use.  I am used Netwide assembler and the following syntax is working perfectly for me

arr DD 100 DUP(?) ; declaring 100 uninitialised 4 byte words

Comment: This is MASM syntax.  Tested in NASM version 2.14.02, and as expected I get an error: `error: comma expected after operand 1`.

Comment: (NASM 2.15 and 2.16 added more MASM compatibility syntax features so this might work in more recent NASM.  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5 / https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1)