# Error Raised When Attempting to Assign Value At Index of Array With x86 Assembly GNU GAS

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I am using `x86` GNU assembly with GCC and am attempting to implement the Assembly equivalent of the following `c/c++`:

```
int x[10];
x[0] = 5;
```

However, when I attempt to run (with command `./a.out`) my Assembly code below (after first compiling  with the `gcc filename.s`), the error `Segmentation fault: 11` is printed to the console:

```
.data
  x:.fill 10
  index:.int 0

.text
.globl _main
_main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $16, %rsp
  lea x(%rip), %rdi
  mov index(%rip), %rsi;
  movl $5, %eax;
  movl %eax, (%rdi, %rsi, 4);
  leave
  ret
```

In order to declare the array, I followed the instructions found here: [Declaring Arrays In x86 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545696/declaring-arrays-in-x86-assembly#answer-29546316).

Does anyone know why this behavior is happening? I am running this code on Mac OSX with the `gcc` compiler using `GNU GAS` syntax.

Comment: If you want 10 integers (4 bytes) you'll need to do something like `x:.fill 10, 4` . Your version allocates 10 bytes (size of 1 is default if not specified)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much! If you could write your response in an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @MichaelPetch, the byte size must be including with the `.fill` statement:

```
x:.fill 10, 4
```